# Possible numbers of outcome of 'i'

Tags: c++, c, operating-system, processor

```
int i=5;
f()
{
    i++;
    i--;
}
```

For the above code if three threads execute the above function `f()` simultanously then what can be the total different values of global variable `i` are possible?

Note : `i` is initialized to 5 globaly.

Comment: 5, 6, 7, 8?  Seems pretty obvious... but then again, I haven't studied what happens when you perform thread-unsafe operations that extensively.

Comment: @bdares - what makes you think this?

Comment: this question was asked to me in interview

Comment: @bdares - please explain the output

Comment: @KirilKirov each thread can increment once before decrementing, so if each thread is executed halfway before moving on to the next thread, we get 3 of the +1s.

Comment: As far as the standard is concerned, behavior is undefined, so really the interview question needs to establish a bit more context. Any result is *legal*, as is any behavior. Even ignoring the possibility that it could crash, it makes a difference whether or not we should assume that the optimizer might re-order the two statements in the function -- I think it affects how plausible `2` and `8` are.

Comment: @bdares - now see Tony The Lion's answer.

Comment: @SteveJessop I imagine that any decent optimizer will turn `f()` into a no-op.  Which would make the behavior defined at a lower level, and result in `i == 5`, regardless of how many threads accessed `i`.

Comment: @James: that's certainly plausible. I suppose that in practice, either the optimizer is on (in which case it will do as you say) or off (in which case nothing would be reordered). So there's no need to consider the plausible effects of `i--; i++;` as well.

Comment: @SteveJessop Even with no optimization, there can be reordering in the hardware (read or write pipeline, etc.).

Comment: @James: good point, although personally I wouldn't predict how (or if) that will affect the result, since I don't know what rules apply to such transformations in hardware. I'd sort of guess that for hardware to be sane, they'd be stricter than the reordering rules for C++, if only because C++ explicitly says that in the absence of `volatile` all bets are off.

Comment: @L.ppt It was likely a trick question. Any candidate trying to come up with a predictable outcome of the code most likely lacks experience of writing multi-threaded applications.

Comment: @Lundin: heh, so any candidate who don't express at least a sharp intake of breath isn't hired. The ideal candidate flatly refuses to even consider the question, but submits a bug report on the code (with proposed patch) in the interview :-)

Comment: @SteveJessop The reordering rules of the hardware can't be looser than those of C++, because if they were, you couldn't implement a conformant compiler on the hardware.  My point wasn't that they were tighter or looser, only that the reordering took place even when you told the compiler to do no reordering (no optimization).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I would say that's an exercise in combinatorics, which I'm personally not going to do, however I do want to make clear that this is **NOT** the correct way to have threads execute this `f()`.  The problem is that the implementation of `operator++` is not a single instruction, which means that halfway through one call to `operator++` it could context switch and do another `f()` in another thread.  This would then lead to corrupt state of your variable `i`.

So determining the possible values of `i` without proper synchronization is useless, since it could be any number of values, real or unreal, as things might go corrupt.

Answer (score 6):

Suppose the ++ operator is defined as the instructions:

> ```
> 1) Load the memory location holding i into register A. 
> 2) Add one to the value stored at register A. 
> 3) Store register A back into memory holding i."
> ```

Now we have 3 threads and because there is no synchronization tools in place there is no guarantee about when the OS will context switch between these threads.

So here is a possible scenario.

> 1) Thread 1 loads i into register A. Register A holds the value 5.
>
> 2) Thread 1 adds one to register A. Register A now holds the value 6.
>
> 3) The OS context switches to Thread 2.
>
> 4) Thread 2 loads i from memory into register A *overwriting the previous value there*. Register A now holds the value 5.
>
> 5) Thread 2 adds one to register A. Register A now *again* holds the value 6.
>
> 6) Thread 2 stores register A back into memory for variable i. i holds the value 6.
>
> 7) OS context switches back to Thread 1.
>
> 8) Thread 1 continues where it left off, stores register A back into memory for variable i. i *still* holds the value 6.

Here we have "successfully" run through two complete increment operators and have resulted in only adding one value to the variable. Oh the dangers of multithreading...

Comment: Gah, you wrote a nearly identical example as me, at the same time. I suppose there is no point in posting mine then :) The important thing here is knowing that the access to i++ isn't atomic, so there isn't necessarily a number of deterministic result. Trying to investigate exactly what will happen in detail, for a particular platform, isn't really interesting to anyone, not even for educational purposes. T

Comment: Also note that (if the values involved were larger) writes aren't atomic either, if one thread saves 257, and another 8, the result coukd be 264!

Answer (score 2):

The program has infinitely many possible outcomes (even though there are only finitely many possible values of an `int` variable) since it has invoked undefined behavior by accessing the same object from multiple threads with no synchronization.

I assume your instructor wants a small number answer based on combinatorics, but per the C language that's wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Is it a homework?
I think any integer value from between 3 and 7 is the answer.

- 8 cannot happen, because the last thread will decrement the value without any interference from other threads.
- 2 cannot be reached because at least the first incrementation will be succesful.
- We assume that memory read/write is atomic. Otherwise strange bit-level operations could happen.

If you turn optimisations on, though, I would expect that i won't be actually changed by any of the threads.

Comment: "Anything below 5 cannot happen either because every decrementation happens after incrementation in the same thread." - says who?

Comment: i++ is most likely not an atomic operation, so there is no telling what the result might be. `i` can get corrupted at any moment, by any context switch.

Comment: @Lundin: I am not talking about atomicity of i++, I am talking about atomicity of memory read or write. If thread A tries to store 4 and thread B tries to store 1 under memory cell x, what will be the final result? 4? 1? Or perhaps 5 (request gets or-ed)? Or something else? I assume that at least one of thread A and B will succeed in writing a correct value. That's what I mean by saying 'read/write is atomic'.

Answer (score 0):

`i` can go from `00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000` to `11111111 11111111 11111111 11111111` in binary, assuming it is an `int32`.

There you go.